# How many ways can 4 out of 7 rooms be allocated to 7 people if only their exposition matters? (3 to the West, 4 to the East)

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

Disclaimer: This is self-study stuff (outside of semester) and I am asking why my solution (way of thought) is wrong to better understand what it is that I am doing wrong.

The problem:
4 people go into holdiays where 7 rooms are available. Each one can choose a single room for himself. Only one person per room. Three rooms look to the west, while 4 look to the east.

How many ways are there to allocate the rooms when only the exposition to the west or east matter?

I thought of the following table

| West | East header |
| --- | --- |
| 3 $\rightarrow \binom{3}{1} = 3$ | 1 $\rightarrow \binom{4}{1} = 1$ |
| 2 $\rightarrow \binom{3}{2} = 3$ | 2 $\rightarrow \binom{4}{2} = 6$ |
| 1 $\rightarrow \binom{3}{1} = 3$ | 3 $\rightarrow \binom{4}{3} = 4$ |
| 0 $\rightarrow \binom{3}{0} = 1$ | 4 $\rightarrow \binom{4}{4} = 1$ |

Then I would think to multiply and add the possible partial allocations:
$$3 * 1 + 3 *6 + 3 *4 + 1 *1 = 3 + 18 + 12 + 1 = 34$$

However, 34 is not correct.

I "simulated" the problem and got 15 which is the correct answer. (code below if interested).
I now wonder, what I am doing wrong in my approach in the mathematical approach above.

---

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
# dirty creation of vectors in a tibble that are then crossed 
#        (crossed ~ all combinations created)

poss <- data_frame(a = paste("R", c(1:7), sep = "")) 
# poss for possibilities
aux <- data_frame(b = paste("R", c(1:7), sep = ""))
poss <- add_column(poss, aux)
aux <- data_frame(c = paste("R", c(1:7), sep = ""))
poss <- add_column(poss, aux)
aux <- data_frame(d = paste("R", c(1:7), sep = ""))
poss <- add_column(poss, aux)

# create all combinations which are 7^4
comp_poss <- poss %>% expand(a, b, c, d)
comp_poss %>% nrow() # = 7^4 = 2401

comp_poss <- data.frame(comp_poss) # for index-based subsetting.
keep <- c() # empty vector with all rows that are to be kept

# loop to remove impossible allocations such where a room is used twice
for (i in 1:nrow(comp_poss)){
  aux_eval <- length(unique(c(comp_poss[i, ]) %>% unlist())) == 4
  keep <- c(keep, aux_eval)
}


# declaring which three rooms are west. 
# the precise definition of which rooms are west-facing should not matter.

west_rooms <- c("R1", "R2", "R3")

# looping and replacing the rooms for their direction west (W) or east (E)
for (i in 1:nrow(comp_poss_reduced)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(comp_poss_reduced)){
    # i <- 1; j <- 2
    aux_val <- comp_poss_reduced[[i, j]]
    
    if(aux_val %in% west_rooms){
      aux_direction <- "W"
    } else{
      aux_direction <- "E"
    }
    
    comp_poss_reduced[[i, j]] <- aux_direction
  }
}
# Solution:
unique(comp_poss_reduced) %>% nrow() # = 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you account for distinguishable rooms and indistinguishable people. It should have been the other way around.

Consider assigning each person to east or west, where the room numbers don't matter. If there were plenty of rooms both side, we'd have $2^4$ choices in total, e.g. $\{WWWW,WWWE,...,EEEE\}$. All but one of them is possible (i.e. $EEEE$) because there are 3 rooms in the east side. So, you have $2^4-1=15$ different situations.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!